# I need to export a rigged Blender model to Maya

Tags: export, file-format, distort

I am supposed to move a model I have built in blender into Maya. The model looks fine in blender, but no matter what I do I can't get it into Maya properly. I understand that the constrains on the bones are not transferable and the best solution would probably be to not export the bones at all with the mesh. There are parts of the model other than the legs that are not constrained to an armature that that are being distorted beyond recognition and I can't figure out how to fix this. Does anyone know why this is?
[image]The model in Blender

[image] And in Maya

Comment: Have you made sure you have applied all transforms in blender before exporting?

Comment: I would probably try unparenting the mesh from the armature, import them separately, and redo the weighting and bone constraints in Maya. It's possible the weighting would not need to be done entirely, but since the mesh is not deforming as you expect, I think you will need to address this issue first. Maybe isolate one leg first and just try to get it to deform correctly, then if that works, apply the technique to the rest of the model. I don't use Maya, so I can't really give any more specific advice than that.